# How to Add white-space: nowrap Style in GWT Table StylesBuilder

Tags: gwt, whitespace

I am building a GWT table and I need to add nowrap style. I have the following:

```
private TableRowBuilder rBuilder;

TableCellBuilder res = rBuilder.startTD();                  
StylesBuilder resStyle = res.style();
```

I found WhiteSpace enum in Styles class but I can't find any suitable method to add in in StylesBuilder API.  How can I make my table cells have nowrap style?

Answer (score 0):

I did it by adding an attribute directly to the TableCellBuilder:

res.attrubute("style", "white-space: nowrap");